# Last character of label text not properly displayed in user control form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

In a custom task pane for office, I use a few labels, all text is set in the Visual Studio editor. The pane is designed like this:
[image: Valid XHTML].

Notice the text in the red circle. When I load my application in Excel, the pane looks like this:
[image: Valid XHTML].

As you can see, the last 't' of the text is not displayed. When I change the text to 'commenp', the last character is displayed.

Why is this? And how can I fix it?

Edit: I just found out that if I change the text to "Commentt", it is displayed as "Comment". But still I would like to know why...

Comment: Look through your code and make sure nothing edits the label.

Comment: I did, I created a new pane to test this...

Comment: I can't see the images. Maybe the width of your label is dynamic. If that is the case, the formula to calculate the width might not work properly with the font you are using. Try setting it to a fixed width.

Comment: @the_lotus: Thank you! Apperantly 'autosize' was set to true, and somehow that does not work with a 't' at the end... If you could write this as an answer, I can accept this.

Comment: @DrDonut I posted an answer, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the "autosize" property is set to true. The calculation to find the width may be a bit off with the font you are using.

Comment: I would never have thought that the text size calculation could be wrong! I thought that was impossible. :)

Answer (score 0):

try increasing the width of the label, see if that helps.
When the form is in Excel, check if the text is getting hidden because of the cell width.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but if I add 5 more characters to the text (not ending with a 't') they are all displayed without any problems...